# Is it possible to adjust badge description to flow automatically

Tags: bug, user-interface

When I see the badge description on hover, I see the description goes only on top of the badge and not below (Even if it is on the top of the page). Attached screenshot for reference.

If the badge is on the top of the screen its description can be on downwards[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug, but it's a *really* minor one...

Comment: I agree, but just wanted to make it notice